# android amazon sdk S3 strange issue for putObject

Tags: android, sdk, upload, amazon-s3

I found one strange thing when I am use amazon's aws-android-sdk. My application put some files to bucket and after this when I try to get this file from another device - file can be gone (it appears may be 1 of 15 tries). But after some time(not long) - file appears and I can take it. My code here:

```
final AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(sharedAccessKey,sharedSecretAccessKey);
client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
final PutObjectResult result = client.putObject(bucket, key, localFile);
```

After this I check that result not null and send notification to another device to get this file. Why i see this delay between sending and availability? What is workaround for this ?

update: My another phone is iPhone where i try download file using presigned url

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its called 'eventual consistency' and there is not much you can do about it, other then wait. I generally find that uploading an object to S3, then immediately checking if its there (like within 100ms) will often fail. Waiting a few seconds is usually fine, but sometimes things can get a little sticky it seems.

More detail below. US Standard, since it stores data on left and right coasts can e worse in this regard.

http://shlomoswidler.com/2009/12/read-after-write-consistency-in-amazon.html